# What does ' !self ' means in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

From [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/86521/how-to-make-a-view-controller-transition-animation-like-in-the-ping-app) I have seen this kind of "!" + self like operation, what does it exactly means in Swift ?

```
override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation!, finished flag: Bool) {
  self.transitionContext?.completeTransition(!self.transitionContext!.transitionWasCancelled())
  self.transitionContext?.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)?.view.layer.mask = nil
}


!self.transitionContext!.transitionWasCancelled()  //returns true
self.transitionContext!.transitionWasCancelled()   // without ! , return false
```

Comment: Its just means "not".   If something is true and you put ! in front of it then it becomes false, or vice versa. Its not being applied to self, its being applied to transitionWasCancelled()

Comment: `!` in front of a `Bool` value as in your example is equal to the NOT operation, so if `.transitionWasCancelled()` returns `true` and you take the NOT operation, it would result in `false`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put a (mental) bracket around it:

```
!(self.transitionContext!.transitionWasCancelled())
```

It means "logical not". So if `self.transitionContext!.transitionWasCancelled() = true`, pass `false` into the function `completeTransition` and vice-versa.

The `!` in `self.transitionContext!` is [optional unwrapping](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) in Swift and has nothing to do with logic though.

Comment: Thank you very much !
i really got confused when seeing '!' on Swift lol

Answer (score 1):

It's not a **Swift**-specific thing, it's the `not` operator. I.E. `true == !false`